# What is the difference between now = datetime.datetime.now() and now = datetime.now() in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between `now = datetime.datetime.now()` and `now = datetime.now()` in Python? Why does `datetime` need to be repeated?

Comment: When we talking about datetime.datetime, the first one datetime is package, the second is a class inside the 3rd party lib. If only import datetime, you should use now = datetime.datetime.now(); but if imported like "from datetime import datetime", you can use now = datetime.now()

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import datetime

>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 11, 30, 26, 254912)

>>> datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

>>> type(datetime)
<class 'module'>

>>>type(datetime.datetime)
<class 'type'>
```

datetime is a python module in which "DateTime class" is present. When we call datetime.datetime, a new object is created of that class. "DateTime class" has different functions which provide the date, year, month, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In brief, if you want to use multiple features of the `datetime` package, you will probably

```py
import datetime
```

and need to refer to `datetime.datetime.now()` by its full name.  If you only need features which are in `datetime.datetime`, you can abbreviate it by doing

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

and then `datetime.now()` resolves to `datetime.datetime.now()` because the symbol `datetime` actually refers to `datetime.datetime` within your source file.

The nested structure with two identical labels referring to both the library and a specific submodule is not an ideal design.  Many Python packages (both in the standard library, and more broadly) have unattractive `import` conventions where the only thing you could possibly want to `import` needs to be imported with the `from package import submodule` syntax, or you are stuck with having to use `package.submodule` whenever you want to refer to something in `submodule`.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` will almost guarantee that someone else working with your code will screw up by referring to datetime.datetime (not that its hard to fix)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `now = datetime.now()` will work if you are just doing `import datetime`

For your question as to why datetime is repeated.

When we say `import datetime`, we are importing a module called datetime. In that module there are different base classes for further operations. They are `date, time, datetime` etc.

Basically the second datetime is the name of class to deal with both date & time manipulations. If you wanted to do only date related operations you could use `datetime.date` class. For further clarification check the official doc

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html